# E: Package 'cassandra' has no installation candidate when installing Cassandra

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cassandra

I was trying to uninstall and reinstall Cassandra on my Ubuntu system however in an attempt to cleanup I deleted file names with cassandra in it, and accidentally deleted requisite file including the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list file. And now when I try to install Cassandra using the command `sudo apt-get install cassandra`, it gives the error `E: Package 'cassandra' has no installation candidate`. How can I fix this?

I ran `sudo apt-get update` and the cassandra.sources.list file seems to have come back, with content `deb [arch=amd64] https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian 311x main` but it still gives same error on trying to install cassandra

Answer (score 3):

I was able to follow the [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html) to install cassandra, the only thing that I adjusted was the `curl -L flag` but apart from that this can solve your problem.

```
$ echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 40x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 40x main

# Make sure the `cassandra.sources.list` file has only this single line.

$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 40x main

$ curl -L https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   227  100   227    0     0   4283      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4283
100  267k  100  267k    0     0   296k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  296k
OK

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cassandra
```

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that APT was not able to find a source for the package:

```
E: Package 'cassandra' has no installation candidate
```

The cause for the error is that you added the wrong repository in your sources:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian 311x main
```

If you have a look at the [Cassandra installation document](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing) I wrote on the Apache website, the correct repository is `www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian`.

If you want to install Cassandra 3.11, You need to delete your source and update it with:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
$ echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

You'll need to follow the document above to add the repo keys and update the package index on your server. Then to install C* 3.11.11 (for example), run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cassandra=3.11.11-1
```

You'll need to adapt the command above to the specific version you want to install. Otherwise, APT will attempt to install the latest version. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

The comment above solved my problem ^

deb [arch=amd64] https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/debian 311x main

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32918542)